# How to connect to database and run stored procedure in asp.net 5 / vnext - no EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I want to set up a very simple open / read example where I connect to a SQL Server instance with a connection string, run a stored procedure and get the result set.

All of the ASP.NET 5/ vNext / MVC 6 examples I see are Entity Framework.  I *don't* want to use that.  I just want to connect to the database with a 'raw' SQL Connection, and I want to scope that connection correctly using DI.

So what I'm thinking is that in my startup.cs I have something like:

```
services.AddInstance<ISQLConnection> (new SQLConnection {connectionString=".."});
```

And then I might create a data object like :

```
DataObject db = new DataObject();
```

where DataObject has a constructor :

```
public void DataObject(ISQLConnection connection)
{
  _connection = connection;
}
```

And methods like this:

```
public List<Items> GetItems()
{
   IDataReader rdr = _connection.RunSp("GetItems");
   while (rdr.Read())
   {
     // fill list etc
   }
   return items;
}
```

I'm finding it difficult to get traction on this problem - all I see is references to EF.  I want to understand it at a deeper level than that - and keep it cross-platform.

If you have already written something like this please share.

Comment: ADO.NET `SqlCommand` https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310070

Comment: I don't believe that ado.net connections have changed at all so it should be exactly the same as with previous .net versions. The way you get your connection string from your config file has changed but that's a different matter

Comment: That's missing the question - obviously I know how to open a data connection.  The question is how to do this using DI, not how to actually run a stored procedure.

Comment: Then I believe you are making a mistake comparing entity framework to SqlConnection. Managing dbcontext instances and scope is not the same as managing sqlconnection instances and scope. Entity framework opens and closes database connections as needed. So for your scenario, the equivalent would be to open a connection in the method which calls the stored procedure and dispose it at the end. Now if you were to use the repository pattern and put your sp calls within those, then the repositories may be good candidates for DI but I think what you are talking about is too low level for DI.

Comment: Yes, perhaps the question is badly worded and badly titled.  I was pretty tired when I wrote it.  I essentially want to build my own 'dbcontext' which would manage the connection open/close at the time of the query, but passed around a *base* object which had the connection string etc stored.  This would be handled with DI in the same way that EF does, without being EF.

Comment: Before writing your own implementation have a look at some of micro-ORMs available out there - [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net), [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/)